# How to get rid of boundary lines in ggplot geom_hex

Tags: r, ggplot2, hexagonal-tiles

I really like the idea of a hexbin density plot in ggplot, and I try to use it (instead of a square-shaped bin as produced by stat_bin2d) whenever I can. However, the boundries of the hexagons are sometimes obvious. For example,

d <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(carat, price))

d + stat_binhex()

[image]

In this picture the boundaries of hexagons show up as little white lines, which sometimes interferes with my attempt to conceive the true "density" variations in the picture.

If I use stat_bin2d, the boundaries lines are not shown at all :

d <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(carat, price))

d + stat_bin2d()

[image]

So my questions are:

1. Why the hexagon boundaries are displayed while square boundaries aren't.
2. More importantly, is there a way to do stat_hexbin without showing boundary lines?

Thanks very much!

Aside: I prefer to do hexagon density plot in ggplot rather than using some other package mainly because I like the flexibility of adding other layers to it later on.

Comment: Possible workaround: you could just change the color of the outline to match the color of hexagons themselves, something like `stat_binhex(color = 'royalblue4')`

Comment: Thanks Teja. It sounds plausible, but when I tried it the pic doesn't look very satisfactory...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the link to [ggplot2 multiple stat_binhex() plots with different color gradients in one image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13167531/ggplot2-multiple-stat-binhex-plots-with-different-color-gradients-in-one-image) as a reference I was able to do what you are asking with the following code:

```
d <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(carat, price))
d + stat_binhex(aes(colour = ..count..))
```

or

```
d <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(carat, price, colour = ..count..))
d + stat_binhex()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Now I understand in stat_binhex(aes(colour = ..., fill = ...)), colour controls cloring the boundary, fill controls coloring the inside of each hexagon. Although I didn't say in the original question, in my real problem I wanted to add other layers in the picture, where I need to use scale_color_manual to provide colors for a few discrete colors.  For example, on top of the blue-ish density plot, I want to plot a few outlier points in red. That gives me a problem because I have to choose either a discrete or a continuous color scale in one plot, but not both

Comment: on "choose either a discrete or a continuous color scale in one plot, but not both": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11508902/plotting-discrete-and-continuous-scales-in-same-ggplot